# Does System.Linq.Enumerable.Reverse copy all elements internally to an array?

Tags: .net, linq, .net-4.0

Some years back, [somebody complained about the implementation of `Linq.Reverse()` and Microsoft promised to fix that](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/355096/system-linq-enumerable-reverse-does-not-provide-optimized-implementation-when-its-argument-is-an-ilist-t). This was in 2008, so the question is, does Framework 4 have an optimized implementation of `Linq.Reverse()` that does not materialize the collection (i.e. copy all elements  to an internal array) when the collection type allows it (e.g. `IList<T>`)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Obviously it's not possible to optimize all cases. If some object implements only `IEnumerable<T>` and not `IList<T>`, you have to iterate it until the end to find the last element. So the optimization would be only for types that implement `IList<T>` (like `T[]` or `List<T>`).

Now, *is* it actually optimized in .Net 4.5 DP? Let's fire up <s>Reflector</s> ILSpy:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Reverse<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    return ReverseIterator<TSource>(source);
}
```

Okay, how does `ReverseIterator<TSource>()` look?

```
private static IEnumerable<TSource> ReverseIterator<TSource>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    Buffer<TSource> buffer = new Buffer<TSource>(source);
    for (int i = buffer.count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        yield return buffer.items[i];
    }
    yield break;
}
```

What that iterator block does is to create a `Buffer<T>` for the collection and iterate backwards through that. We're almost there, what's `Buffer<T>`?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct Buffer<TElement>
{
    internal TElement[] items;
    internal int count;
    internal Buffer(IEnumerable<TElement> source)
    {
        TElement[] array = null;
        int length = 0;
        ICollection<TElement> is2 = source as ICollection<TElement>;
        if (is2 != null)
        {
            length = is2.Count;
            if (length > 0)
            {
                array = new TElement[length];
                is2.CopyTo(array, 0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (TElement local in source)
            {
                if (array == null)
                {
                    array = new TElement[4];
                }
                else if (array.Length == length)
                {
                    TElement[] destinationArray = new TElement[length * 2];
                    Array.Copy(array, 0, destinationArray, 0, length);
                    array = destinationArray;
                }
                array[length] = local;
                length++;
            }
        }
        this.items = array;
        this.count = length;
    }

    // one more member omitted
}
```

What have we here? We copy the content to an array. In every case. The only optimization is that if we know `Count` (that is, the collection implements `ICollection<T>`), we don't have to reallocate the array.

So, the optimization for `IList<T>` is **not** in .Net 4.5 DP. It creates a copy of the whole collection in every case.

If I were to guess why it isn't optimized, after reading [Jon Skeet's article on this issue](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/08/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-27-reverse.aspx), I think it's because that optimization is observable. If you mutate the collection while iterating, you would see the changed data with the optimization, but the old data without it. And optimizations that actually change behavior of something in subtle ways are a bad thing, because of backwards compatibility.

Comment: Tip: IlSpy functions similarly to Reflector, I'll leave ideological issues aside, but it's capable of decompiling iterator blocks to functions with the `yield break;` and `yield return;` statements.

Comment: I think you and Jon are right that this optimisation hasn't been implemented because it's a breaking change. Interesting that the Connect issue mentioned by the OP has a comment from Ed Maurer stating that they did plan to implement it.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for digging Svick!!

Comment: @hvd, you're right, it can do that. I have updated the code in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Breaking change? Seems to me like that only applies to those who made assumptions *not backed by the documentation*, which can bite you in *any* situation. Say, if `Dictionary` ever stops maintaining order (which it currently does as long as you don't delete anything), you should never have relied on this undocumented behavior in the first place. Seems to me like the `Enumerable.Reverse()` optimization can readily be applied.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Yes, it appears that this change has been made

The bug report you linked to marks the bug as Fixed, but I wanted to make sure for myself.  So, I wrote this little program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> bigList = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000000).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine("List allocated");
    Console.ReadKey();

    foreach (int n in bigList.Reverse<int>())
    {
        // This will never be true, but the loop ensures that we enumerate
        // through the return value of Reverse()
        if (n > 100000000)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", n);
    }
}
```

The idea is that the program allocates 400 MB of space into `bigList`, then waits for the user to press a key, then calls `Enumerable.Reverse(bigList)` via extension method syntax.

I tested this program with a Debug build on a Windows 7 x64 machine.  My memory usage before starting the program is exactly 2.00 GB, according to Task Manager.  Then, before I hit a key, memory usage reaches 2.63 GB.  After I hit the key, memory usage briefly spikes to 2.75 GB.  Importantly, though, it does not spike by 400 MB or more, which would be the case if `Enumerable.Reverse()` were making a copy.

**ORIGINAL POST**

It's impossible for a correct `Enumerable.Reverse()` implementation not to copy to an array or other data structure in some situations.

The complaint you link to deals only with `IList<T>`.  In the general case, though, I argue that `Enumerable.Reverse()` *must* copy the elements to some internal buffer.

Consider the following method

```
private int x = 0;

public IEnumerable<int> Foo()
{
    for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++)
    {
        yield return n;
        x++;
    }
}
```

Now let's say that `Enumerable.Reverse()` didn't copy the input `IEnumerable<T>` to a buffer in this case.  Then, the loop

```
foreach (int n in Foo().Reverse())
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", n);
```

would iterate all the way through the iterator block to get the first `n`, all the way through the first 999 elements to get the second `n`, and so on.  But this wouldn't have the same effect on `x` as forward iteration, because we would be mutating `x` every time we iterated almost all the way through the return value of `Foo()`.  In order to prevent this disconnect between forward and reverse iteration, the `Enumerable.Reverse()` method *must* make a copy of the input `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: And is the implementation optimized for `IList<T>` in .Net 4?

Comment: It's impossible "in some situations": the situations in which you have no `IList<T>`.

Comment: @svick I don't know if the implementation is optimized for `IList<T>` in .NET 4.  Maybe ask one of the BCL devs?  Unfortunately, I don't know any BCL developers myself.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin, there are simple ways to find out: implement `IList<T>` and watch what methods does `Reverse()` call. And there are also complicated ways (see my answer).

Comment: Watching task manager is not very good way to measure memory, especially since allocating your list creates **a lot** garbage. Memory consumption before/after `foreach` measured using `GC.GetTotalMemory()` for me is 768MB/893MB without forcing collection, and 512MB/893MB when forcing collection. This data indicates the optimization is **not** implemented.