# Why there is two completely different version of Reverse for List and IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable, reverse

For the `List` object, we have a method called [Reverse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2.aspx).
It reverse the order of the list 'in place', it doesn't return anything.

For the `IEnumerable` object, we have an extension method called [Reverse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx).
It returns another IEnumerable.

I need to iterate in reverse order throught a list, so I can't directly use the second method, because I get a List, and I don't want to reverse it, just iterate backwards.

So I can either do this :

```
for(int i = list.Count - 1; i >=0; i--)
```

Or

```
foreach(var item in list.AsEnumerable().Reverse())
```

I found it less readable than if I have an IEnumerable, just do

```
foreach(var item in list.Reverse())
```

I can't understand why this 2 methods have been implemented this way, with the same name. It is pretty annoying and confusing.

Why there is not an extension called BackwardsIterator() in the place of Reverse() working for all IEnumerable?

I'm very interested by the historical reason of this choice, more than the 'how to do it' stuff!

Comment: You could use Enumerable.Reverse(list)

Comment: Why don't you just have your list typed to the type that you like, and then it will use the version of the method you like?

Comment: ^ presumably he "likes" it to be a `List`, since it is a `List` -- but, as he clearly said, he doesn't want to use `List.Reverse`. "typed to the type that you like" means casting it, which isn't any prettier than using `AsEnumerable()`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is worth noting that the list method is a lot older than the extension method. The naming was likely kept the same as `Reverse` seems more succinct than `BackwardsIterator`.

If you want to bypass the list version and go to the extension method, you need to treat the list like an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
var numbers = new List<int>();
numbers.Reverse(); // hits list
(numbers as IEnumerable<int>).Reverse(); // hits extension
```

Or call the extension method as a static method:

```
Enumerable.Reverse(numbers);
```

Note that the `Enumerable` version will need to iterate the underlying enumerable entirely in order to start iterating it in reverse. If you plan on doing this multiple times over the same enumerable, consider permanently reversing the order and iterating it normally.

Comment: Actually, even if one is only going to want to enumerate the thing once and wanted to keep the original list undisturbed, I would expect that it would almost certainly be faster to call `ToArray()` and then call `Reverse()` on the resulting array, than to use `Enumerable.Reverse()`.  The `List<T>.ToArray()` method can store data in the target array as a block without having to process individual items, while `Enumerable.Reverse()` will--unless it has special handling for the case where the source is a `List<T>`--have to copy items into an array one at a time before reversing them.

Comment: @Supercat The chances are good that it has special casing. I've used ILSpy on some other methods in the past and they were special cases on `IList` a lot of the time.

Comment: There are indeed many special cases, but there are also some annoying wrinkles.  For example, although a `List<Cat>` may be passed to code which expects an `IEnumerable<Animal>`, such code will not be able to exploit any special "list-ness".  My "almost certainly" language was perhaps a bit strong, though an advantage of converting to an array before enumeration is that if I recall correctly C# generates special code when using a `foreach` loop on something it knows to be an array. Even if `Enumerable.Reverse` returns the enumerator of the temporary array, the compiler won't know that.

Comment: @supercat It's definitely a good shout, plus you get the added benefit of not relying on the inner workings of the current linq implementation for any performance gains.

Comment: If you want to play code golf, instead of the cast I would rather call `numbers.Skip(0).Reverse()`, it is more readable from left to right, and you are dealing with an `IEnumerable`. It is also nicer than `numbers.OfType<int>().Reverse()` since it doesn't put in the overhead of a useless type check on every entry.

Comment: There is also `numbers.Reverse<int>()`, which one of the extension's overloads.

Comment: With the availability of the .Net Framework Reference Source, you can see that `Enumerable.Reverse` has special handling for `ICollection<>` which adds a `Count` and `CopyTo` operation; special handling for `IList<>` would seem to be worthwhile but isn't present.

Comment: *It is also nicer than numbers.OfType<int>().Reverse() since it doesn't put in the overhead of a useless type check on every entry* -- quite the strawman. The OP suggested the sensible `AsEnumerable()`, not `OfType<int>()`. *There is also numbers.Reverse<int>(), which one of the extension's overloads* -- that's not an "overload", and it will still invoke `List<T>.Reverse<T>`, not `IEnumerable<T>.Reverse<T>`.

Answer (score 5):

Write your own BackwardsIterator then!

```
public static IEnumerable BackwardsIterator(this List lst)
{
    for(int i = lst.Count - 1; i >=0; i--)
    {
        yield return lst[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to make a utility method out of it you should use a more efficient method (i.e. a backwards for loop).  `Reverse`, as an IEnumerable, is rather inefficient as it needs to iterate the enumerable, store it in a buffer, and then iterate the buffer in reverse.

Comment: @Servy you are right..specially if the list is `huge`!..thx to point it out

Answer (score 2):

The existence of `List<T>.Reverse` long preceded the existence of `IEnumerable<T>.Reverse`. The reason they are named the same is ... incompetence. It's a horrible botch; clearly the Linq `IEnumerable<T>` function should have been given a different name ... e.g., `Backwards` ... since they have quite different semantics. As it is, it lays an awful trap for programmers -- someone might change the type of `list` from `List<T>` to, e.g., `Collection<T>`, and suddenly  `list.Reverse();`, rather than reversing `list` in place, simply returns an `IEnumerable<T>` that is discarded. It cannot be overstated just how incompetent it was of MS to give these methods the same name.

To avoid the problem you can define your own extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Backwards<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) => source.Reverse();
```

You can even add a special case for efficient processing of indexable lists:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Backwards<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) =>
    source is IList<T> list ? Backwards<T>(list) : source.Reverse();

public static IEnumerable<T> Backwards<T>(this IList<T> list)
{
    for (int x = list.Count; --x >= 0;)
        yield return list[x];
}
```