# MyStack.Reverse() not working

Tags: c#, stack, reverse

I want to reverse the stack so element at TOP should be at zero and vice versa. I know it may not be a right operation to do this but I want to do this. And if not I want to know why this not works

When I do

```
List<string> MyList = new List<string>();
MyList.Reverse()
```

It works. But not this one.

```
Stack<string> MyStack = new Stack<string>();
MyStack.Reverse()
```

Any Idea/ Solution??

Thanks & Regards,

Ganesh

Comment: Of what type is `MyStack`? And whatexactly is *not working*?

Comment: See [How does IEnumerable<T>.Reverse work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051612/how-does-ienumerablet-reverse-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `MyList`is of type `List<T>` and `MyStack`is of type `Stack<T>`:

`List<T>` defines a method named `Reverse` which reverses the order of the elements in the List [...]
But `Stack<T>` does **not** define such a method.
There is an **extension method** `Enumerable.Reverse<T>` that **returns** the elements in reversed order.

So you could try this:

```
MyStack = new Stack ( MyStack.Reverse() );
```

MSDN:

- [`Stack<T>` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/76atxd68.aspx)
- [`List<T>.Reverse()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/5c6526tb.aspx)
- [`Enumerable<T>.Reverse()` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb358497.aspx)

### Update

As @Dennis_E mentioned in his answer and comment, calling above line of code would reverse the stack **twice** - meaning that MyStack will stay the same... So the correct answer is

```
MyStack = new Stack(MyStack);
```

Comment: Combine this answer with mine and you've got it. MyStack.Reverse() will return the top item last and so the stack will be in the same order as it was. You need MyStack = new Stack(MyStack);

Answer (score 0):

A stack is already in reverse, so to speak.
If you have a stack with items A,B & C, with A at the top, reverse() gives you C,B,A, but if you add those to a stack again, A will be on top again. (C will be added first, then B and then A)

Comment: Nope. I want to reverse the current order